# Installation & Varnish Test Results and MFTF Magento Supplied Results Fails on Magento Marketplace

Tags: magento2, composer

[image]

> composer.json

```
{
    "name": "vendor/preorder",
    "description": "preorder",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "2.0.4",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "~7.0.13||~7.1.0||~7.2.0||~7.3.0||~7.4.0"
    },
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "app/code/Vendor/Preorder": ["vendor/preorder"]
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com"
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "magento/marketplace-tools",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/magento/marketplace-tools",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "origin/master"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Vendor\\Preorder\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you post your report.json file? This provides valuable info

Comment: @M.Sonah  I'll post a file in few  minutes

Answer (score 1):

You should check your module first. See if it's actually breaking the cache.

Then you can always open a ticket for Marketplace staff to check it for you.

Here is the link to submit a ticket: https://marketplacesupport.magento.com/hc/en-us/requests

Answer (score 0):

after escalating with Magento Engineering the solution is to using \Proxy for some command line codes.

Find your console type name in di.xml to make use of \Proxy in your argument

```
<type name="Maurisource\Lightspeed\Console\Command\LsSyncAll">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="lightspeedService" xsi:type="object">Maurisource\Lightspeed\Api\LightspeedServiceInterface\Proxy</argument>
        <argument name="state" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\State\Proxy</argument>
        <argument name="area" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\Area\Proxy</argument>
        <argument name="helper" xsi:type="object">Maurisource\Lightspeed\Helper\Data\Proxy</argument>
        <argument name="lockHelper" xsi:type="object">Maurisource\Lightspeed\Helper\Lock\Proxy</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Read the full guide on how I addressed this failure:
https://maurisource.com/fixed-magento-marketplace-installation-varnish-test-results-failure/